# Forbid Azure AD User access to Microsoft Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an enterprise application that uses Azure AD for auth. The company employees have individual Azure AD accounts (e.g. name@my-company.com). There is no IP/location based restriction. The question is how can I restrict access from those accounts only to my application and forbid access to other Microsoft Services (such as office.com, etc) using the company account?

Comment: How about not assigning them any licenses? That way they will not be able to make use of any services like Office365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security -> Conditional Access -> New Policy
You can create a policy for a Group of users, Applications granting access or denying to whatever you need.

[image]